# the DRIBBBLE question

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

> Does anyone have a [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com) invitation to give? This is my email xxx@xxx.com

I think that many designers would love to ask this question, but I feel as the same time something to not ask in this environment (I don't know why, I just feel that this could be the kind of things that people could try to fight for). What you think guys?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is most definitely **Off-topic**. Remember that Stack Exchange sites are suppose to act as repository of information, a question like this adds no value at all to the site. Just like requests for beta keys to new apps or games are off-topic for Gaming and Super User, requests for invites to communities like Dribbble and Forrst should not be tolerated here.

Additionally, there are other mediums, like email, social networking sites and even [our own chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/188) that should accept requests like this perfectly fine.

Therefore I suggest that any such question be closed with extreme prejudice.

Comment: I would remove the "extreme prejudice", it is a bit harsh :)

Comment: I would not remove the extreme prejudice.  There is no room for such questions.